# jquery.html array as a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code for getting a data from api for 2 different URLs. The result is positive when I use `$('#resultDiv1').html` instead of `opts[j].html`. On using `opts[j].html`, I am getting error as `opts[j].html` is not a function'. Where is the mistake? Please help me.

```
var domain = "https://example.com/api#token=";
var detail = "/some_data"

$(document).ready(function() {
    var token = ['260105', '49409' ];
    var resultElement1 = $('#resultDiv1');
    var resultElement2 = $('#resultDiv2');
    var opts = ["resultElement1", "resultElement2"];
    for (j=0; j<1; j++){
        $.ajax({
        url: domain + token[j] + detail,
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            opts[j].html(response.data.candles[response.data.candles.length - 1][4]);

        }
    })
    }

});
```

Comment: @31piy after correcting to 

for (j=0; j<2; j++)

I found that it works only if I write the code as

var k = token.length;
for (j=0; j<k; j++){
        $.ajax({
        url: domain + token[j] + detail,
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            opts[j-k].html(response.data.candles[response.data.candles.length - 1][4]);

        }
    }

Comment: @31piy after correcting to 

for (j=0; j<2; j++)

I found that it works only if I write the code as

var k = token.length;
for (j=0; j<k; j++){
        $.ajax({
        url: domain + token[j] + detail,
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            opts[j-k].html(response.data.candles[response.data.candles.length - 1][4]);

        }
    }

For token, it is taking j = 0 then j = 1 but for opts, its is taking initial j = 2 then j = 3. That's why I introduced k here.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because `"resultElement1"` and `"resultElement2"` are two different strings in the `opts` array. To use the selected elements, you need to create array using the variables `resultElement1` and `resultElement2`, like this:

```
var opts = [resultElement1, resultElement2];
```

Also, your `for` loop will only work for `resultElement1`, because you end the iteration as soon as `j` becomes `1`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have applied all changes as you said. now opts[j] is not showing any result. Instead opts[0] and opts[1] are showing results.

Comment: @Anurag -- Please observe your console for any errors. Also, see the **Network** tab to see if appropriate request/response is generated.